# How to handle Firebase Database error in iOS? #AskFirebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to handle "Permission Denied" error differently from all other errors.

In Android I've done it: (Kotlin)

```
override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
    if (error.code == DatabaseError.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        // Warn user
    }
}
```

In iOS I have only:

```
someDbReference.observe(.childAdded, with: { data in 
    // Do something
}, withCancel: { err in
    // err is Error
    print((err as NSError).code) // 1
    // Which error? O_o
})
```

How to determine error type? I've read whole documentation, and I think that `err.localizedDescription == "Permission Denied"` is a really bad way.

Comment: I think you can see if `error.code` is unique for that specific error. Then check if that specific code is present

Comment: @kathayatnk "Value of type `Error` has no member `code`"

Comment: Hmmm... Are you sure `err` is `NSError` and not `Error`?

Comment: @paper1111 it's `Error`, casted to `NSError`, but `error.code` doesn't equal to `-3`

Comment: does it always prints 1?. If so you can use that instead of -3

Comment: @kathayatnk I can't be sure, but I think yes, since Firebase error codes are always below zero (Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseError Unity: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/database-error)

Comment: According to source code documentation on FirebaseDatabase, it says that 
`The cancelBlock will be called if you will no longer receive new events due to no longer having permission.` So I believe it will be invoked only on `permission denied`. If that is the case you don't have to check for specific error in there

Answer (score -1):

Just like it was already mentioned in the comments, I use same approach to determine type of error Firebase returns. Eg:

```
    someDbReference.observe(.childAdded, with: { data in 
        // Do something
    }, withCancel: { (returnedError: Error) in
        // Casting Error to NSError
        let testError: NSError = searchError as NSError

        // This is just random error from FB documentation, you can find all there
        if testError.code == FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeUserDisabled.rawValue {
          // User disabled
        }
      })
```

Make sure you cast returned error object which is type of Error to NSError. Use its error code to compare it to Firebase error code.

Comment: In `FIRAuthErrorCode` all codes are starting at `17000`, but I receive code `1`, this won't ever work. But it looks like Firebase bug, because I should receive code `-3` for permission denied

Comment: Oh you are right. It slipped my mind - I am handling errors with custom Error class because I use few languages in app and need to localise. So that error is under `default switch case` and is used as general error message.
Will keep on visiting your post in case you find anything new, hope you figure something out.

Comment: I hope that someone from #askfirebase or maybe @FrankvanPuffelen will answer =)

Comment: `FIRAuthErrorCode` is for Auth errors only. I haven't found a way to find DatabaseErrorCode I am looking for the same thing.